# SQL Server connection failure

Tags: sql-server, connection-string

I have a library that handles connections to my database. It has a connection string that includes the credentials needed to login to the database. I am referencing that library with several apps. It works in all but one. It used to work for that one but stopped with the most recent library build. It comes back with a Connection refused for user XXX. The SSMS logs record it as a password mismatch Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State 8.

I've provided the connection string just in case you want to see, but I think it must be something trickier than a connectionstring typo, since it's working elsewhere.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="POIRepository.Properties.Settings.MoMConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=database;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=password"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I can login directly into SSMS using the same credentials as well. I don't really see how this is possible. Does anyone have any ideas of things to try?

Comment: Probably the simplest of all: the password is incorrect (cASe sEnsiTiVitY catches a lot of folks here). Note that it will say "the login provided" even if you attempted to connect as a contained database user but forgot to specify a database, specified the wrong database, or typed the password incorrectly - unless it finds a match, SQL Server doesn't have any idea you were attempting to use a contained database user.

Comment: You sure the broken app is using the correct version of the library?

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/2020/07/28/troubleshooting-error-18456

Comment: @TheGameiswar if the OP is correct in that they are using the connection string in multiple places, how would case sensitivity be the issue if the connection string is the same?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Yes. I have even copied the dll that's being used right now on production down to my local machine and referenced that copy. I cleaned the app. I'm as sure as I know how to be anyway.

Comment: @TheGameiswar I agree that the error indicates that I am giving it the wrong password, but I can't see how. I only have the password typed in one place, and it's correct. I can copy and paste it to sign in directly to SSMS with it. I can't figure out how to debug to see what is actually getting submitted to SQL, though. Maybe my connectionstring is getting overwritten somewhere or something. It's the best I can come up with but I don't know how to debug it.